# 5 children, named Johnny, Jodi, Jimmy, Jerry and Jackie are queued up in a straight line. Jackie will be ahead of Jimmy in 60 of these arrangements?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a true or false question.

I can understand how we can get 60, however I believe it is false as this ONLY assumes Jackie and Jimmy to be beside each other right?

Not very sure about this, appreciate the help

Comment: There are $5!$ arrangements of the five children. Due to symmetry, half of them will have Jimmy ahead of Jackie and the other half will have Jackie ahead of Jimmy.

Comment: Probably means Jackie will be somewhere ahead of Jimmy in the line, not necessarily immediately ahead.

Comment: To clarify, it was mentioned in the question it is possible for some of the other kids to be placed in between Jackie and Jimmy, so yes jackie doesn't have to be immediately ahead.

Answer (score 4):

There are $5!=120$ arrangements and in *each* of them Jackie will be ahead of Jimmi or Jimmi will be ahead of Jackie. Further these events are *mutually exclusive*.

Then on base of symmetry we draw the conclusion that in $60=\frac12\cdot120$ of all the arrangements Jackie with be ahead of Jimmi.

Answer (score 1):

For calculate it manually compute ( select r guys which are behind of jimmy and rearrange remember jackie is not one of them)

> $$\sum_{r=0}^3.\binom{3}{r}(4-r)!.r!$$

$$=\binom{3}{0}.4!.0!+\binom{3}{1}.3!.1!+\binom{3}{2}.2!.2!+\binom{3}{3}.3!.1!$$
$$=24+18+12+6$$
$$=60$$